# How do I update Array Elements matching criteria in a MongoDB document?

Tags: mongodb

I have a document with an array field, similar to this:

```
{ 
  "_id" : "....",
  "Statuses" : [
    { "Type" : 1, "Timestamp" : ISODate(...) },
    { "Type" : 2, "Timestamp" : ISODate(...) },
    //Etc. etc.
  ]
}
```

How can I update a specific Status item's Timestamp, by specifying its Type value?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From mongodb shell you can do this by

```
db.your_collection.update(
    { _id: ObjectId("your_objectid"), "Statuses.Type": 1 },
    { $set: { "Statuses.$.Timestamp": "new timestamp" } }
)
```

so the c# equivalent

```
var query = Query.And(
    Query.EQ("_id", "your_doc_id"),
    Query.EQ("Statuses.Type", 1)
);

var result = your_collection.Update( 
    query, 
    Update.Set("Statuses.$.Timestamp", "new timestamp", UpdateFlags.Multi,SafeMode.True)
);
```

This will update the specific document, you can remove _id filter if you wanted to update the whole collection

Comment: Is there any way to update whole object except it's id ?

Comment: Worth to mention that it will update ONLY FIRST matching element.

Comment: @JohanWillfred — I added an answer that addresses the situation where there may be multiple matching array elements: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68093337/1108305

Answer (score 11):

Starting with MongoDB 3.6, the [`$[<identifier>]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#mongodb-update-up.---identifier--) positional operator may be used.  Unlike the [`$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) positional operator — which updates at most one array element per document — the `$[<identifier>]` operator will update every matching array element.  This is useful for scenarios where a given document may have multiple matching array elements that need to be updated.

```javascript
db.yourCollection.update(
  { _id: "...." },
  { $set: {"Statuses.$[element].Timestamp": ISODate("2021-06-23T03:47:18.548Z")} },
  { arrayFilters: [{"element.Type": 1}] }
);
```

The `arrayFilters` option matches the array elements to update, and the `$[element]` is used within the `$set` update operator to indicate that only array elements that matched the `arrayFilter` should be updated.

Comment: can I use this method in updatemany?

Comment: @MohdFaizan_06 Yes you can use (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#update-all-array-elements-that-match-arrayfilters)