# mongodb upsert in updating an array element

Tags: mongodb

Want to upsert in object properties in a array of a document

Consider a document in collection m

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("524bfc39e6bed5cc5a9f3a33"), 
 "x" : [       
    { "id":0.0, "name":"aaa"},{ "id":1.0, "name":"bbb"}  
 ]
}
```

Want to add `age:100` to `{ "id":0.0, "name":"aaa"}` .
Not just age .. But but provision for upsert in the array element {}. So it can contain `{age:100,"city":"amd"}` (since i am getting this from the application service)

Was trying this... But did not worked as it replaced the entire array element

```
db.m.update({_id:ObjectId("524bfc39e6bed5cc5a9f3a33"),
     "x" : {
                "$elemMatch" : {
                        "id" : 0.0
                }
}},
{
        $set : {
                "x.$" : {
                    "age": 100
            }
        }
},
{upsert: true}
)
```

Changed the document to (which i did not wanted)

```
 { "_id" : ObjectId("524bfc39e6bed5cc5a9f3a33"), 
     "x" : [       
        { "age":100},{ "id":1.0, "name":"bbb"}  
     ]
    }
```

Is this possible without changing schema.

Answer (score 7):

```
$set : {"x.$" : {"age": 100}}
```

`x.$` sets the entire matched array element to `{age: 100}`

This should work:

```
db.m.update({_id:ObjectId("524bfc39e6bed5cc5a9f3a33"),
"x.id": 0.0}, {$set: {"x.$.age": 100 }});
```

Using `elemMatch`:

```
db.test.update({x: {$elemMatch: {id: 1}}},{$set:  {"x.$.age": 44}})
```

Note that the `upsert` option here, is redundant and wouldn't work if the `id` isn't present in `x` because the positional operator `$` doesn't support `upserting`.

Comment: I know this works. But i am asking if db.test.update({x: {$elemMatch: {id: 1}}},{$set:  {"x.$":{"a":100,"b":200,"age": 44}}}) would work ?? Or something similar works . Note {"a":100,"b":200,"age": 44} could be object and it should "upsert" values in the matched item of the array.

Comment: Yes, but it'll **replace** the entire matched element with the new document: `{"a":100,"b":200,"age": 44}`. And it cannot `upsert` values because an `upsert` is performed only if a match isn't found(an element in `x` isn't present with the specified `id`).

Comment: >>upsert is performed only if a match isn't found,, nah! on matched documents properties are updated/ inserted

Comment: This is from the MongoDB docs: **If set to true, creates a new document when no document matches the query criteria. The default value is false, which does not insert a new document when no match is found.**

Comment: also if you try to update with upsert set, you are adding to the properties; and not replacing the document.

Comment: Yes, bro. What I was trying to say is that if you know, in advance, that a match will be found, then specifying the `upsert` option is redundant. `upsert` = update the matched document or insert a new one if a match isn't found.

Comment: Using of $ is not possible via upsert according to official docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without changing schema. If you can change schema to use an object to store your items (rather than an array), you can follow the approach I outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871363/upsert-array-elements-matching-criteria-in-a-mongodb-document/21347039#21347039).