# MongoDB: Add and remove from array field at the same time

Tags: mongodb

I want to rename tags in our documents' `tags` array, e.g. change all tags `a` in the collection to `c`. The documents look something like this:

```
[ { _id: …, tags: ['a', 'b', 'c'] },
  { _id: …, tags: ['a', 'b'] },
  { _id: …, tags: ['b', 'c', 'd'] } ]
```

I need to keep tags **unique**. This means, an update like this will not work, because the first document will end up containing tag `c` **twice**:

```
db.docs.update(
    { tags: 'a' },
    { $set: { 'tags.$': 'c' } }
)
```

So, I tried this alternatively:

```
db.docs.update(
    { tags: 'a' },
    {
        $pull: { 'a' },
        $addToSet: { 'c' }
    }
)
```

But this gives a `MongoError: Cannot update 'tags' and 'tags' at the same time`.

Any chance of renaming the tags with one single update?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pull and addtoset at the same time with mongo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24300148/pull-and-addtoset-at-the-same-time-with-mongo)

Answer (score 1):

According to [official MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/), there is no way of expressing "replace" operation on a set of elements. So I guess, there isn't a way to do this in single update.

**Update**:
After some more investigation, I came across [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) document. If I understand it correctly, your query should look like this:

```
db.docs.update({
       tags: 'a'
  }, {
    $set: { 'tags.$': 'c'}
  })
```

Where 'tags.$' represents selector of the first element in "tags" array that matches the query, so it replaces first occurence of 'a' with 'c'. As I understand, your "tags" array does not contain duplicates, so first match will be the only match.

Comment: Thank you for you response. Concerning your update: This is what I tried first. But it'll create duplicates: If `c` is already in the array, `a` will be renamed to `c`, and there are two `c`s in the array.

Comment: Ah! It seems I've missed that part. Then I guess first part of my answer apply, which states that you can't express that intent clearly in single operation.
I don't quite know if mongodb update doc can contain nested queries.
Even if it can, then it's quite a hassle to write, because what you will need to express is "distinct( union(minus($row.tags, ['a']), ['c']) )", in sql terms, which looks painful even in this simplified form.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say then, is you'll have to first addToSet a 'c' element everywhere where 'a' is contained, and then run second update that will remove 'a'.

Comment: This was what I had, but I had hoped there was some more elegant solution :) But your feedback and the older question linked above also confirms that this is the way to go. Thanks!