# Not able to perform 2 operations on document in same mongodb query ?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am currently trying to build a swap query for my database, i currently have the following: `db.customers.findOneAndUpdate(
            { 
                name 
            }, 
            {
                currentCustomer: swapCustomerId, 
                $push: { 
                    que: currentCustomerId 
                }, 
                $pull:{ 
                    que : swapCustomerId 
                }
            }, {
                new: true
            })`

Executing this query gives me the following error : `Cannot update 'que' and 'que' at the same time`.

I have read about Bulk writes, but i cant find a way to access a specific document to edit with it ?

Any ideas on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is a MongoDB restriction in which you cannot perform two sets of operations on the same key:value pair. You can have them in separate atomic operations,ergo your going to have to perform them individually with two separate queries.

Refer to this : [Pull and addtoset at the same time with mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24300148/pull-and-addtoset-at-the-same-time-with-mongo)