# How to use push and pull in single query mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to mongo now I trying to do in MongoDB push and pull query concept in the array. I want to pull all object and push the new object into an array while using pull alone its working fine and same push alone working fine but i used both in single query i tired but not able to achieve my need help to solve this
Note:UIList array is Dynamic

## My Query

```
 db.getCollection('roles').update(
    { "_id": ObjectId("5bd6b1dc552a2a3ed0bde948") },
    { "$pull": { "UIList": {  } } },
    { "$push":  {$set: "UIList": { "field1": "1234", "field2": "12345" } } }) //Not working
```

Comment: answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24300148/pull-and-addtoset-at-the-same-time-with-mongo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As design you can't apply multiple update modifiers to the fields. You can use `$set` with array which will overwrite the existing array values.

Something like

```
db.getCollection('roles').update(
    {"_id": ObjectId("5bd6b1dc552a2a3ed0bde948") },
    {"$set":{"UIList":[{"field1":"1234","field2": "12345"}]}}
)
```

Comment: thanks but my values are dynamic i am not do any hardcode i forgot this in question that's why i am trying in pull and push method idea?

Comment: You can pass anything to $set as long it resolves to array like `{$set:{UIList:my dynamic array }}`.