# How to update the entire object inside an array using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Mongoose with Typescript; my current document look likes this:

```js
{
    _id: 1,
    id: "a",
    markets: [{
        type: "car",
        price: 10000},
        {type: "toy",
        price: 10},...]
}
{
    _id: 2,
    id: "b",
    markets: [{
        type: "car1",
        price: 1023400},
        {type: "toy1",
        price: 1032},...]
}
{
    _id: 3,
    id: "c",
    markets: [{
        type: "car2",
        price: 10000},
        {type: "toy2",
        price: 1023},...]
}
```

I want to update particular `{type: "car", price: 10000}` this part base on `id` and `type` (given that id="a" and markets.type="car" before updating), which they should all be unique:
for example: use `{type: "car3", price: 11200}` to update
`{type: "car", price: 10000}`, how can I do it in Mongoose?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I update Array Elements matching criteria in a MongoDB document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967184/how-do-i-update-array-elements-matching-criteria-in-a-mongodb-document)

Comment: no, I wish to update the entire object instead of a key value pair inside the object. @ray

Answer (score 1):

```js
db.collection.update({
  id: "a"
},
{
  $set: {
    "markets.$[element]": {
      type: "car3",
      price: 11200
    }
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      element: {
        type: "car",
        price: 10000
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HOCz3Gm1VtD)

Comment: Thank you, may I ask it is possible to add `upsert=true`, cause I tried, and can't add new object into the empty array inside `market`